# @-names in plain TeX

Tags: tex, texinfo

Texinfo adds macros starting with '@'. I'm curious how to do that in plain TeX because I'm trying to create a simple TeX framework for my friends' needs and it would be more readable for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

texinfo essentially replaces plain TeX's backslash with the at sign. This is done by setting the so-called `\catcode` of the at sign to `0`.

Note that with this setting, `@command` means exactly the same as `\command`, you don't get a second family of command names.

Note also that designing and implementing a new TeX format is a lot of work; it is much easier to resort to one of the existing TeX formats.